# Accessing the logs from s3 bucket using logstash

Tags: amazon-s3

Does accessing the logs from s3 bucket in logstash.conf file would change logs in the s3 bucket?
Actually, I don't want it to alter actual logs in the s3 bucket as it is important for my organization.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The original logs won't get modified. The logs "forwarder or shipper" does only read/tail the input file from source. If specified it can append additional tags/elements to them and sends the information to the logstash instance for further parsing and enrichment.

Comment: Can you please provide me the logstash.conf file to access the s3 bucket logs? @akaTataru